# Flutter hive first load initial value problem

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

I have these errors and i don't know what's the problem,
it's a newly created hive data and doesn't contain any value yet.
I'm trying to load it and if value = null return defaultValue

here's the code for hive load :

```
hiveOperation() async {
  GlobalPosition globalPosition;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  await Hive.openBox('box');
  Hive.registerAdapter(GlobalPositionAdapter());
  globalPosition = box.get('globalPosition');
  lat = globalPosition.latitude;
  lon = globalPosition.longitude;
}
```

this is the hive constructor :

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'storage.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class GlobalPosition {
  GlobalPosition({required this.latitude, required this.longitude});
  @HiveField(0, defaultValue: 1.0)
  double latitude;

  @HiveField(1, defaultValue: 1.0)
  double longitude;
}
```

The error when load is :
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'GlobalPosition'

I don't know how to fix it, please help me, Thank you!

Comment: You can use 'var' keyword or something like <YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE>? to make a variable for globalposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `defaultValue` in `get` method:

```
  globalPosition = box.get('globalPosition',defaultValue: GlobalPosition(latitude:1.0 ,longitude:1.0);
```